# How to use performSegueWithIdentifier from a model class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

So I'm having a bit of a tricky time resolving the following. I'm able to use `performSegueWithIdentifier` to skip between View Controllers using the code as seen below:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toOppHand" sender:self];
```

However, I have a separate model class which hosts a long list of methods, some of which I'd like to use the above code. Obviously, using "self" doesn't work because I'm no longer in a viewcontroller class. So I'm wondering what I need to do in order to modify the code. I originally tried creating an object of the main view controller like so but that didn't work either (received an error saying "Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'toOppHand'"):

```
OneViewController* view=[[OnePlayerViewController alloc]init];
[view performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toOppHand" sender:self];
```

Any help would be much appreciate.

EDIT: Here's a more detailed view of what my program looks like.
EDIT 2: Here's my edit with the suggested answer below.

Model class:

```
#import "OnePlayerView Controller"

@protocol PlayerDelegate
//I have an error here "expected a type".
- (void)playerNeedsCardFromOpponent:(OnePlayerViewController *)player;

@end

@interface model : NSObject


@property (nonatomic, weak) id<PlayerDelegate> delegate;


-(void)playBill:(NSString*)cardName{
    //modifying name so it works with the method (make the below easier)
    NSString* newName=[cardName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    newName=[newName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@""];
    newName=[newName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
    newName=[newName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"!" withString:@""];
    newName=[newName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@";" withString:@""];
    newName=[newName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
    newName=[newName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@""];
    [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(newName)];
}

-(void)CardType1{

    OnePlayerViewController* view=[[OnePlayerViewController alloc]init];
    [view performSegueWithIdentifier: @"toOppHand" sender: self];    

}
```

View Controller:

```
- (IBAction)playCard:(id)sender {
    int cellNumber=self.SelectedRowPointer.row;
    NSString* cardType=[[self.CardsinHandPointer.player1_hand objectAtIndex:cellNumber]cardType];
    NSString* cardName=[[self.CardsinHandPointer.player1_hand objectAtIndex:cellNumber]cardName];
    if ([cardType isEqualToString:@"bill"]){
        [self.CardsinHandPointer addCardtoPortfolio:cellNumber forPlayer:1];
        [self.CardsinHandPointer playBill:cardName];
    }
    if ([cardType isEqualToString:@"location"]){
        [self.CardsinHandPointer playLocations:cellNumber forPlayer:1];
    }
    if ([cardType isEqualToString:@"personality"]){
        [self.CardsinHandPointer playPersonalities:cellNumber forPlayer:1];
    }

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I believe `performeSegueWithIdentifier` would require the view controller to be properly instantiated as part of a storyboard.

Comment: I have the viewcontroller instantiated as part of the storyboard--what I'm trying to do is from Viewcontroller A, trigger method which is defined in model class, which then takes me to Viewcontroller B.

Comment: performSegueWithIdentifer is a method of UIViewController class and model class would not be able to call unless you inherit UIVIewController.  From my understanding of MVC i don't that's even a good idea to do that.   The controller should be controlling segues

Comment: But wouldn't the view controller technically be the one doing the performSegueWithIdentifier? I just have the specific action of it defined elsewhere (the model class)?

Comment: To clarify, I have a list of methods defined in this model class so I can access them from any of the view controllers. I could put these methods into the view controller class instead to solve the issue--however, I need to be able to access said methods from any view controller and having them in a model seems the most efficient way of doing so.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Make it more specific. What exactly does this model class represent?  Pick one of the methods.  What is the method supposed to do?  Why is it called?  How is it called?

Comment: Ok so to break it down basically I've created this card game where the model has the method actions for each card in the deck. Some of the cards require you to look at your opponent's hand (which is where the performSegueWithIdentifer comes in).

On the main view controller, there is a "play X card" button which allows you to play the card whose method is then called from the model class.

Once this method is called, I want it to push to a new viewcontroller (your opponent's hand).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think of your model as needing to present a view controller.  Think of your model as needing to get some data.  To get that data, it's going to send a message to some object, requesting the specific data it needs, and later the model will receive a message providing the data.

So first, define a protocol containing the message or messages the model needs to send to request the data.  For example:

```
@protocol PlayerDelegate

- (void)playerNeedsCardFromOpponent:(Player *)player;

@end
```

Then give the model object a `delegate` property to refer to the object to which it will send these requests:

```
@interface Player (NSObject)

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<PlayerDelegate> delegate;

- (void)receiveCardFromOpponent:(Card *)card;

@end
```

Then your player view controller can set itself as the model's delegate and implement the `playerNeedsCardFromOpponent:` method to perform the appropriate segue.  When the opponent-card-choosing view controller finishes, it can either hand the card directly back to the `Player` (if it has a reference to the `Player`) by sending it `receiveCardFromOpponent:`, or it can pass the card back to the player view controller, which then sends it to the `Player`.

Comment: Thanks very much for this detailed response. I think this is what I'm looking for, though I'm a bit confused on how to implement this.

Firstly, am I defining the protocol in the same model class? Also, why do I need this method "- (void)playerNeedsCardFromOpponent:(Player *)player;"? In my program (which I have updated above with more detailed code), I have methods "CardTypeX" which should trigger the segue to the opponent's view controller. Is this what "- (void)receiveCardFromOpponent:(Card *)card;" is referring to? Sorry, I've only used delegates a few times before so I'm inexperienced.

Comment: Ok I've updated my top post with the edits... still a bit confused here though. I'm getting an error saying it's "expecting a type".